# Twilio not using the username / password defined on the xml

Tags: sip, asterisk, twilio

I'm placing a SIP call, and the xml looks like this

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Sip username="myusername" password="mypass">sip:myext@mydomain.com</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

When I look into the SIP packets I see, on the second INVITE

```
From: "+1XXXXXXXXXX" <sip:+1XXXXXXXXXX@sip.twilio.com>;tag=78774647_6772d868_43fb2951-f4f9-4c80-8377-9bb50e9458ae
```

And no references to myusername... it looks like Twilio is just not sending it, and using the caller id on the from, which is obviously not recognised by my server. On the Asterisk side, I just see

```
[Oct 17 19:22:58] NOTICE[9150]: chan_sip.c:22614 handle_request_invite: Sending fake auth rejection for device "+1XXXXXXXXXX" <sip:+1XXXXXXXXXX@sip.twilio.com>;tag=78774647_6772d868_43fb2951-f4f9-4c80-8377-9bb50e9458ae
```

Which kind of makes sense... on my sip.conf, I have

```
[myusername]
context = somecontext
type = user
secret = mypass
permit=107.21.222.153
permit=107.21.211.20
permit=107.21.231.147
permit=54.236.81.101
permit=54.236.96.128
permit=54.236.97.29
permit=54.236.97.135
permit=54.232.85.81
permit=54.232.85.82
permit=54.232.85.84
permit=54.232.85.85
permit=54.228.219.168
permit=54.228.233.229
permit=176.34.236.224
permit=176.34.236.247
permit=46.137.219.1
permit=46.137.219.3
permit=46.137.219.35
permit=46.137.219.135
permit=54.249.244.21
permit=54.249.244.24
permit=54.249.244.27
permit=54.249.244.28
```

I'm kind of stuck here... if anyone could give me a hint I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... I figured it out. As I guess lots of people will want to integrate twilio with their Asterisks, here's what happened.

The issue is that my server wasn't recognising the user, and it seems like the user/pass is sent after this (twilio doesn't send the user on the From). So, you need to make it `type=peer` and then use the `host=ip` to identify twilio. But... they have 23 ips... so, I used templates.

But for every new ip you add you're adding a new sip device, so you should know which IP twilio is going to use to know which username you need to send. The answer is using `allowguest=yes` on the template... what's good about this, is that it already recognized twilio's ip, so our guest is actually twilio.

This is the xml I'm passing to twilio now

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Sip>sip:myext@mydomain.com</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

(loving the idea of not sending my username and password on it, hating that I bought an SSL cert just to protect them) and this is how my **sip.conf** ended up looking

```
[twiliocaller](!)
context = somecontext
type = peer
qualify=no
allowguest=yes

[twilioip-1](twiliocaller)
host=107.21.222.153

[twilioip-2](twiliocaller)
host=107.21.211.20

[twilioip-3](twiliocaller)
host=107.21.231.147

[twilioip-4](twiliocaller)
host=54.236.81.101

[twilioip-5](twiliocaller)
host=54.236.96.128

[twilioip-6](twiliocaller)
host=54.236.97.29

[twilioip-7](twiliocaller)
host=54.236.97.135

[twilioip-8](twiliocaller)
host=54.232.85.81

[twilioip-9](twiliocaller)
host=54.232.85.82

[twilioip-10](twiliocaller)
host=54.232.85.84

[twilioip-11](twiliocaller)
host=54.232.85.85

[twilioip-12](twiliocaller)
host=54.228.219.168

[twilioip-13](twiliocaller)
host=54.228.233.229

[twilioip-14](twiliocaller)
host=176.34.236.224

[twilioip-15](twiliocaller)
host=176.34.236.247

[twilioip-16](twiliocaller)
host=46.137.219.1

[twilioip-17](twiliocaller)
host=46.137.219.3

[twilioip-18](twiliocaller)
host=46.137.219.35

[twilioip-19](twiliocaller)
host=46.137.219.135

[twilioip-20](twiliocaller)
host=54.249.244.21

[twilioip-21](twiliocaller)
host=54.249.244.24

[twilioip-22](twiliocaller)
host=54.249.244.27

[twilioip-23](twiliocaller)
host=54.249.244.28
```

Hope it saves some of your time! I also wrote a blog post about this at http://blog.gmc.uy/2013/10/asterisk-twilio-receiving-calls-from.html